# Implementing a custom error in global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my `global.asax` file, I have the following code:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception TheError = Server.GetLastError();

    if (TheError is HttpException && ((HttpException)TheError).GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/500.aspx");
    }
}
```

When I navigate to an non-existing page, I get the generic error page. I don't want anything pertaining to custom error in the `web.config` because my plan is to add code to the `global.asax` file to log the exceptions. Is there a way to handle custom error with just the global.asax file?

[image]

Comment: Are you using Cassini, or IISExpress? Which version of .NET?

Comment: using webforms on .net 4.5 and whether it's on IIS or on my local machine the result is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### EDIT:

The answer is **not** obvious, but this seems to explain it: http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/deployment/deploying-web-site-projects/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs

If you scroll down a ways, you'll find this lovely tidbit:

> **Note: The custom error page is only displayed when a request is made
> to a resource handled by the ASP.NET engine.** As we discussed in the
> Core Differences Between IIS and the ASP.NET Development Server
> tutorial , the web server may handle certain requests itself. By
> default, the IIS web server processes requests for static content like
> images and HTML files without invoking the ASP.NET engine.
> Consequently, if the user requests a non-existent image file they will
> get back IIS's default 404 error message rather than ASP.NET's
> configured error page.

I've emphasized the first line. I tested this out in the default template, and sure enough, this URL:

`http://localhost:49320/fkljflkfjelk`

gets you the default IIS page, whereas simply appending a .aspx makes the `Application_Error` kick in. So, it sounds like you need to enable customErrors/httpErrors if you want to have all errors handled.

**For IIS <= 6**, add to `<system.web>`:

```
<customErrors mode="On" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/404.aspx"/>
  <error statusCode="500" redirect="/500.aspx"/>
</customErrors>
```

**For IIS7+**, add to `<system.webServer>`:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
  <remove statusCode="404"/>
  <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
  <remove statusCode="500"/>
  <error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
</httpErrors>
```

I'll leave the original answer in case someone finds it useful.

---

I believe you need to clear the existing error code from the response, otherwise IIS ignores your redirect in favor of handling the error. There's also a Boolean flag, `TrySkipIisCustomErrors`, you can set for newer versions of IIS (7+).

So, something like this:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception TheError = Server.GetLastError();
    Server.ClearError();

    // Avoid IIS7 getting in the middle
    Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;

    if (TheError is HttpException && ((HttpException)TheError).GetHttpCode() == 404)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/404.aspx");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/500.aspx");
    }
}
```

Comment: I put a breakpoint on line 1, go to a non-existent page but still getting the generic error page.

Comment: By "generic error page", do you mean Error.aspx (or whatever the WebForms equivalent is), or the browser's generic error page?

Comment: By generic I mean the default asp error page; see edit.

Comment: Ok, saw the edit: I added <customErrors mode="On" /> in <system.web> in the web.config but it's still not working. I do see the breakpoint and the custom error page when adding .aspx, which is what your answer describes. Still working on it too.

Comment: @frenchie Adding the `httpErrors` section seems to enable error handling in the test project I started; have to remember that IIS7 and up primarily use the `system.webServer` section. Tweak the redirect mode if you prefer redirection rather than rewriting.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like IIS is looking for a page and did not find it.

Make sure:

1. 404.aspx is created
2. customErrors tag from web.config is not present.